# how to manipulate entity field values in drupal 7 in custom module

Tags: 7, entities, hooks

I am creating a Payroll entity in which I have to manipulate different field values based on another field value (see below).

I have the following fields and I want to calculate the bottom four field values from the value of the basic salary field. Is there any function/hook available for this or do I have to write my own custom function?

1. basic salary field
2. da salary(daily allowance)
3. ta salary(travel allowance)
4. epf salary(Employee provident fund)
5. save_salary(Save salary)

Comment: Hi there.  Could you explain this a little further: " i want to manipulate all the field values from the basic salary field"?  What exactly are you trying to do with the other 4 fields?  Are you just trying to *calculate* the values of the other four based on what is filled in for the 1st value in a particular node of that type?

Comment: Yes exactly i wanna do this but i am searching for any contributed module so that i can write my own operations on the different field as per my requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion, now that I understand you're trying to calculate certain values' amounts based on the amount of a different field, would be to use the [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module.

Then you can accomplish what you need without writing a custom module.  Rules are sometimes a little clunky to create, but the module is really reliable - I use rules for all sorts of things, and once you set it up, it works beautifully.

Here are (roughly) the steps you'd need to take to create a rule that modifies a certain field based on another one.  Adjust as you need to, so it suits your particular needs.

1. After enabling the module, go to /admin/config/workflow/rules to add a new rule
2. Set the 'Event' that triggers the rule to be something like '**After updating existing content**'.  That will trigger this re-calculation any time the node is updated
3. Next you'll see that the rule also has 'Conditions' and 'Actions'.  Set the 'Condition' for your rule to be '**Content is of type**' and select the content type you want to apply this rule to from the given list.

   [image]
4. Finally, let's go onto the actions.  You'll have to do two steps for each of the fields you're modifying 1) First calculate the value from the base_salary field (and store in temporary variable -- that's how it works) and 2) set the appropriate field with the value of this temporary variable.  Here are the 'Action' options that correspond to these

   [image]
5. When you're calculating the value for one of the fields, the interface has, by default, a field to select from the top, an operator, and then a text field into which you can enter a number.  If you would rather add/multiply/etc two fields, just change the bottom one to a data selection option with the following button

   [image]
6. If your calculation is more complicated than simply adding/subracting/etc two values, just keep selecting the 'Calculate' value action and keep working on the number with multiple chain operations until you're ready and then add the 'Set a data value' at the end.

Hope this helps! I can't do an entire tutorial on using Rules here, as it's a complicated module, but the above should get you started and point you in the right direction. :0)